# Changes of sign of error term in prime number theorem for arbitrary number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

[Ingham](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa1/aa1116.pdf) showed that, assuming RH, there's an absolute constant $C > 1$ such that for any $x > 1$ the range $[x, Cx]$  contains a number $n$ such that the error term of the PNT at $n$ is positive and a number $n'$ such that the error term is negative.

Is an analogous statement for arbitrary number fields true assuming GRH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kaczorowski has written a few papers on this topic. [One of his more recent papers](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?MR=2730494) gives almost this result, assuming (something somewhat weaker than) the Selberg orthogonality conjecture. The result is stated that the number of sign changes in $[1,x]$ is $\gg \log x$, which usually is deduced from a statement of the type in the OP; I didn't check if that's the case here. You could also go through this paper's references for results from past papers on the topic.